# pandas dataframe grouping by class and timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, class, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dateframe that looks like this:

```
timestamp               class
2019-07-01 00:59:56     A
2019-07-01 11:24:19     B
2019-07-01 12:41:34     B
2019-08-01 05:22:11     A
2019-08-01 07:05:06     A
```

now I need to know how many rows of each class do I have on a particular day.

So the final result should look like this:

```
timestamp       class    count
2019-07-01      A        1
2019-07-01      B        2
2019-08-01      A        2
```

I'm not sure how I should even start to approach the problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.dt.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.date.html):

```
#if necessary
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])

df1 = df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.date,'class']).size().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
    timestamp class  count
0  2019-07-01     A      1
1  2019-07-01     B      2
2  2019-08-01     A      2
```

Or [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) with specify column after `groupby`:

```
df1 = df.groupby([df['timestamp'].dt.date,'class'])['class'].count().reset_index(name='count')
print (df1)
    timestamp class  count
0  2019-07-01     A      1
1  2019-07-01     B      2
2  2019-08-01     A      2
```

Difference is `count` exclude missing values, `size` not. But because here is also passed `class` column to `groupby` in `by` parameter then it working same - both solutions exclude missing values.